# objective-c compilation error

Tags: objective-c, linux, fedora

I'm using Fedora(laughlin). I've done lots of programming in c, and java on this distro.
So i decided to try out some Objective-C programming in linux. I searched lots of pages over the internet and finally found one.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Building_and_Installing_GNUstep_on_Linux

I went as per the instructions given on this page to install `GNUstep`.

Everything went well in the installation. But after writing a small piece of code and compiling it using the command:

```
gcc gnustep-config --objc-flags` -L/usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lgnustep-base hello.m -o hello
```

It gave me the following error:

`/usr/bin/ld: /usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries/libgnustep-base.so: undefined reference to symbol 'objc_msg_lookup'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'objc_msg_lookup' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libobjc.so.2 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libobjc.so.2: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

I'm new to Objective-C. I have no idea where the linker command exists. I tried adding the `/usr/lib` to the `env.` variable. But it didn't work out.
I also tried to find out solutions on their forum(if they had one!!). But they have none.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 9):

It's complaining that you're referencing code that you aren't linking to your application.  Helpfully, it's telling you what's missing and where it is.  Try adding `-lobjc` to the flags.

Comment: Thanks, i'm such a fool! That was so simple! I thought some files were missing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

in my case just adding -lobjc flag to the command line argument it worked perfectly.

```
gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgnustep-base -lobjc firstObjcProg.m -o firstObjcProg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -o hello hello.m -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base
```